iframes is not working in Jenkins job description
I have entered some html code/text in a Jenkins job description. This basically displays some graphs from a html page. I am able to see the links to the html page in the job description (and they work fine too) but I want the actual graphs to be displayed in the Jenkins job description as well. This was working fine but until few days ago, I am seeing only blank boxes with the hyperlinks.
My html code in the job description is as below:
<tr> <td><a
href="http://activity.html?job=current_jenkins_job&test=XYZ"
target="_blank">Activity</a></td> <td><a
href="http://procedures.html?job=current_jenkins_job&test=XYZ"
target="_blank">Procedures</a></td> </tr>
 
<tr> <td><iframe
src="http://procedures.html?job=current_jenkins_job&test=XYZ"
width="750" height="700"></iframe></td> <td><iframe
src="http://activity.html?job=current_jenkins_job&test=XYZ"
width="750" height="700"></iframe></td> </tr>

What is happening here is that there is only partial renderation of HTML tags. The other HTML tags which I have used are working fine except for iframes. I have tried embed instead and that did not work. . Can anyone please help how I can still see the graphs in Jenkins job description? My Jenkins verison is 2.414.3 and OWASP Markup Formatter plugin version is 162.v0e6ec0fcfcf6
I am not sure if Jenkins has deprecated this or its not supported due to some other plugin deprecated and there was a dependency. Any information about this would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Have you checked if the browser made an attempt to fetch the iframe src, by checking the network panel in dev tools? Does the console have anything to say about this? (And why are the host names in those URLs so weird?)

It was working few days back so not sure what changed with respect to jenkins. The URLs are not real and just an example of the actual html page url.

Just repeating what you already said in the question, isn't adding anything useful. What about the things I asked you to check?
